# how to merge graphs in python using pylab?

Tags: python

These are the two graphs which i want to merge. How to merge them using matplotlib

```
from numpy import linspace
from pylab import *
P = linspace(1,2,100)
for i in range(0,100):
    v.append(i)
    v[i] = v1
plot(v,P)
show()

T2 = (P2*10**5*v1)/R
v3 = (R*T2)/(P1*10**5)
vv = linspace(v1,v3,100)
for i in range(0,100):
    Pa.append(i)
    Pa[i] = P1
plot(vv,Pa)
show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: Combine two graphs. As in thermodynamics there are cycles right, so i want to plot that kind of graphs. You can refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_cycle

Comment: Pylab also contains a function called linspace, so with the second import you are shadowing the linspace imported from numpy. These two functions probably do the same, but this is something to watch out for when doing `from library import *`.